# Using the console to look at NLog information

Tags: logging, nlog

I have the following NLog.config in my web application but how/when does the dialog open up and show the information or do I need to start it and navigate to a specific catalog or something?

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.netfx35.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="ColoredConsole"
            name="Debug"
            layout="${message} ${exception}">
      <highlight-row backgroundColor="Black"
                     foregroundColor="DarkCyan"
                     condition="true"/>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="Raven.Client.*" writeTo="Debug"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NLog will not open a dialog where it will dump its messages, you'll basically lose all the data it logs. At least that is my understanding; the Console and ColoredConsole are only useful for console apps. Your best bet is to have the output go into a file. Use something like this:

```xml
<targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/log.txt" />
</targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
</rules>
```

This will create a text file called log.txt in the base directory of your app and it will write all message that have a minimum level of Info (basically everything) to it. Oh, by the way, you can have multiple targets and rules working at the same time; have a look [here](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file) for more info.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you can instantiate a console in parallel of a non-console program by using this:

```cs
static public class LogConsole
{
    static public void Instantiate()
    {
        AllocConsole();
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static private extern bool AllocConsole();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You should include `minLevel` at the logger rules section (that you forgot). This informs the logger about the lowest level of message that should be logged. To be clear:

```xml
<rules>
    <logger name="Raven.Client.*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="Debug" />
</rules>
```